# Ray casting with CSG tree

Tags: c, raycasting, csg

I'm working a project in which I have to perform ray casting and use CSG trees. But I don't know how to use the CSG trees or implement it for this project.
I can do the ray cast and give the final answer. My problem is really how to implement the tree and link it.

Comment: Did you mean CSG?  (Constructive Solid Geometry?)

Comment: Yep, my bad.. I mean CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry) yes.

Answer (score 0):

The following [PhD thesis](http://www.nigels.com/research/#Thesis) details various CSG rendering techniques in OpenGL. Part of the thesis illustrates how CSG trees are constructed and simplified. A [program (with full C++ source code)](http://www.nigels.com/research/#Download) demonstrates the various algorithms mentioned in the thesis and will also give you an implementation of a CSG tree.